# Wikipedia API not returning anything for some queries

Tags: php, javascript, html, api, wikipedia

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<form action="check2.php" method="POST">
    Search <input type="text" name="search" />
    <input type="submit" name="searchbtn" value="search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $string = $_POST['search'];
    $convert = rawurlencode($string);
    $url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&redirects&titles='.$convert;
    if($_POST['search'] != '' || $_POST['search'] != null) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $c = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $c;
    } else {

    }
?>
```

It returns the XML if I search for (example) "New York" but returns nothing if I search for "Singapore Zoo"

Comment: What's the content of `$c`?

Comment: Have you looked in `$c`?

Comment: I removed `parse_str($c, $txArr); var_dump($txArr);` and echoed $c. The last two were test code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're [supposed to set a User-Agent](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy). Second, that's not a search, that's an export for the page at a specific title; you're looking for [action=opensearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Opensearch).

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=api&limit=1&namespace=0&search=Singapore_Zoo&utf8=true gives:

```
["Singapore_Zoo",["Singapore Zoo"],["The Singapore Zoo (Chinese: 新加坡动物园; pinyin: Xīnjiāpō Dòngwùyuán; Malay: 'Taman Haiwan Singapura'; Tamil: சிங்கப்பூர் விலங்குக் காட்சிச்சாலை), formerly known as the Singapore Zoological Gardens and commonly known locally as the Mandai Zoo, occupies 28 hectares (69 acres) on the margins of Upper Seletar Reservoir within Singapore's heavily forested central catchment area."],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Zoo"]]
```